# How to pass Data to the server in form-data format?. I am trying to send following JSON data. I am using Alamofire

Tags: swift

I am trying to send the following JSON data. I am using Alamofire. There is a JSON file that I want to send

```
[ 
    {
        "DeviceID": "Demo",
        "RemoteID": "123",
        "vBrandName": "VU",
        "vModelName": "VU1",
        "vRemoteType": "TV",
        "RemoteAction": [
            {
                "vActionName": "CH+",
                "vActionCode": "123",
                "RemoteStatus": 0
            },
            {
                "vActionName": "CH-",
                "vActionCode": "12345",
                "RemoteStatus": 0
            },
            {
                "vActionName": "CH-0",
                "vActionCode": "123456",
                "RemoteStatus": 0
            },
        ] 
    }  
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your server-side, but you can try to execute a request something like this:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)
```

I used the Alamofire a long time ago, but the last project where I needed to send the `form-data` was something like above.
Also, it may necessary to pass the `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type in headers

## Edit

If you want to send an array to the server you can try two ways. It depends on what your backend-side supports.
The first way is to create some Codable struct

```
struct SomeStruct: Codable {
    let someArray: [SomeItem]
}
```

The second way is to create `Data` from the array

```
let data = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array)
```

And then pass this data to the Alamofire request method

Comment: How Can send Array in parameter

Comment: @PoojaPuri I've updated my answer. Please check